# Change filter effect depend on menu selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have `menu` with `prev` and `next` button on it like this :

[image: prev-menu-next]


with `html` code like this :

```
<div id="filter" class="filter-container">
  <span id="prev" class="filter-button">&#10096;</span>
  <div class="filter-menu"><option value="C1">C1</option></div>
  <div class="filter-menu"><option value="F2">F2</option></div>
  <div class="filter-menu"><option value="G3">G3</option></div>
  <div class="filter-menu"><option value="P5">P5</option></div>
  <div class="filter-menu"><option value="HB1">HB1</option></div>
  <div class="filter-menu"><option value="HB2">HB2</option></div>
  <span id="next" class="filter-button">&#10097;</span>
</div>
```

then i have `photo-container` like this :

[image: polaroid container]

Prob 1 : I'm using [CSSCO - VSCO FILTER](http://www.cssco.co/) for the effect, but how do i implement this filter on `filter-menu` ?

Prob 2 : I tried to use one of the class to check if the filter working, but when i capture using `html2canvas` the filter doesn't captured.

I was thinking how to do : 
 1. Using jquery `.addClass();`, **i have never tried this. I don't know how to do**.
 2. Using `::after` for the filter, **It doesn't work**. 
 3. Create new `<div>` element using `position: absolute;` stack with `<img>`, **It's blocking `.draggable();` for `<img>`**. 
 4. Manual filtering using `css`, **`html2canvas` ain't capturing the filter**.

Anyone have a clue how do i solve this problem ? Thanks